# Add a svg and show some text on the parts of that view when the user hover or click on that part in WordPress

Tags: svg

I am working in my WordPress website and I want to add a svg to my website and show some text on the parts of that view when the user hover or click on that part in WordPress.

I have searched a lot and I am not getting any reference.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to create an SVG and using the tooltip js, you can show any content on the hover.

Ex: https://strykerdesigns.com/